# 2.4.4 Advanced Content Tools Disappeared

Tags: php

Apache
Operating System
CentOS v7.9.2009

Slowly building a small 2.4.4 Magento and 8.1php simple store.
Everything going smooth. 30 items entered so far.
Went to enable PageBuilder and it is not there.
Everything else on the page below the WYSIWYG options are missing too.
This is the first time I have been on this page. So I do not when this happened or how it happened.
Luma theme. No extensions. Hmmmm.

Is there a way to bring these Advance Content Management Tools back to life? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I restored going back to the April 18th and it is not there as well.

I attached a screenshot if it helps.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk0kk.png)

Thank you in advanced.
Chris

Comment: 2.4.4 of what? I think you forgot to tell us, and tag, what framework/CMS you're using.

Comment: @ADyson judging by the version it's Magento, or otherwise OP's got retro Apache there.

Comment: Apache Operating System CentOS v7.9.2009